# How to get latest timestamp for kafka topic using Python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka

How to get latest timestamp for kafka topic using Python?

Answer (score 0):

As of Kafka 0.10.2, every record that's consumed has a timestamp.

If you want to get the latest record, then you must seek to the end of the topic before consuming.

There is no way to get a timestamp without reading any records.

How to access the timestamp should be reffered to the documentation for the library you are using.